# Get the SEF URLs for articles in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I use 'No Editor' in Joomla with SEF URLs enabled. With no SEF enabled it's easy to know the URL by just getting the ID of the article. Something like:

Article 1 would be: 
http://www.abc.com/j15/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=1

Now if I have SEF switched on, I would get URLs that look like: 
http://www.abc.com/j15/the-content.html

Is there a way inside Joomla where I can find out what the SEF URL for a particular page is?

Currently I add these articles to a menu, then from the front-end I get the SEF URL and then use it. I know the process is a little dumb, but I want to find out if there is a better way inside Joomla where you can get the SEF URL (using 'No Editor').

Comment: Alias is supposed to be for this option. help says : "The Alias will be used in the SEF URL." -- but using the alias with .html .htm (without anything) doesn't work(404) - I have all 3 SEO options selected. I checked the database(table : jos_menu) an entry for a new link that routes to the numbered article is created when the article is added as a menu item. couldn't find anything else of use in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload a component, sh404sef or ARTIOsef, to the administrator panel. Here you can manage SEF URLs as well as the old URL and what new name you want to give it.